# JSON parsing issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, stringify

I have below result returned from python script

> ```
> {"a_paget_wilkes": "\/speaker\/a_paget_wilkes.json",
> "aaron_clark": "\/speaker\/aaron_clark.json",
> "aaron_dunlop": "\/speaker\/aaron_dunlop.json",
> "aaron_ernst": "\/speaker\/aaron_ernst.json",
> "aaron_hurst": "\/speaker\/aaron_hurst.json",
> "abigail_miller": "\/speaker\/abigail_miller.json",
> "abner_kauffman": "\/speaker\/abner_kauffman.json"}
> ```

So it is pretty well formatted JSON I believe. Javascript variable which has above data is called `jsondata`. Now in the chrome developer tool console when I try to access key valye pair by typing `jsondata.` I expect all keys to be listed as suggestion, but it shows me string properties like `length, anchor, big, blink` etc... instead

I tried even `JSON.stringify` first and then `JSON.parse` but still the same!!!

Any idea what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1):

`jsondata` is apparently a string containing your JSON, rather than a JavaScript object that would result from parsing your JSON.

To parse it, use `JSON.parse`.

> I tried even `JSON.stringify` first and then `JSON.parse` but still the same!!!

`JSON.stringify` will take you in the wrong direction — it will wrap your entire string in a JSON string — and `JSON.parse` will only undo the `JSON.stringify` (recovering your original string), not parse your original string.

You need to call `JSON.parse` *without* calling `JSON.stringify` first.

Comment: Now I am getting below

```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:16```

code where I parse it is 
```pyshell.PythonShell.run('py/speakers.py', null, function (err, res) {
        if (err){
            alert('Error :' + err);
        } else {
            var jsonDat = JSON.parse(res[2].toString());
            console.log(jsonDat);
        }
    });```

Comment: No wait....I just got what I was doing wrong! I was returning ```json.loads``` from my python script instead of ```json.dumps```. I just corrected that and now all is well!!! Thanks for help, much appreciated.